# Camera Preview not filling iPad screen in Landscape

Tags: ios, ipad, ios6

My app is iPad only, and supports only Landscape View.

I have a `UIImagePickerController` which loads the Camera.
I set it up with the following code:

```
m_Pickercontroller=[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init ];
m_Pickercontroller.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
m_Pickercontroller.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
m_Pickercontroller.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
m_Pickercontroller.showsCameraControls = YES;
m_Pickercontroller.navigationBarHidden = YES;
m_Pickercontroller.toolbarHidden = YES;
m_Pickercontroller.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
m_Pickercontroller.allowsEditing=NO;
```

It is presented with `[self presentViewController:m_Pickercontroller animated:YES completion:nil];` I have also tried with a Modal and get the same result.

This occurs on first open of the view only.  If you reopen the camera or retake the picture, it goes away.

I have also tried setting the `m_Pickercontroller` frame size, both before and after it is loaded.

Here is what it looks like, black area is empty, white area is the camera preview.  Ignore the white line overlay, that is part of the app.
[image: ugly black bar on first camera open]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this makes no since whatsoever but what was causing this was the animation:yes

I changed `[self presentViewController:m_Pickercontroller animated:YES completion:nil]`
to `[self presentViewController:m_Pickercontroller animated:NO completion:nil]`

and this issue has fixed itself.  apparently iOS does not resize the camera preview after animating the view in.